# Build selected modules Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a central 'core' module which contains things such as database and configuration. I also have multiple plugin modules for different platforms such as Eclipse, IntelliJ and Netbeans which depend on the core module. Is there a way I can build one of the plugins with the core module or build all plugins at the same time and save them under different names? Is this something Maven is made to do and if not is there something better suited to what I want to be able to do?

Comment: Could you give a little bit more context of your current project(s) structure? Is it a multi-module one or different independent modules?

Answer (score 1):

I think probably what you want to do is create a parent project for your modules.  Use a folder structure like this.

```
/parent
    /core
    /Eclipse
    /IntelliJ
    /NetBeans
```

Your parent project's `pom.xml` will look something like this.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>your.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>Eclipse</module>
    <module>IntelliJ</module>
    <module>NetBeans</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

You'll also need to add something like this snippet in each of the child modules

```
<parent>
  <groupId>your.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>whatever</version>
</parent>
```

Once you're set up like this, running `mvn install` (for example) in the parent project will build all of the child modules (including the core).  Running `mvn install` from within a child module will build *only that* child.  Since the plugin modules already depend on the core, they should already work (though if you change the core, you'll have to `mvn install` the core to make them aware of the updates, naturally).